# Phone gap Toggle view is behaving weird after update android webview client

Tags: android-webview, cordova-plugins, phonegap-build

I have list of collapsible view i am using view.toggle(500) code to collapse and expend with animation of 500 millisecond. It was working fine until i update my android web view client. Now its looking bad when i expend and collapse.   I am using phonegap cordoava to create android application.

**Edit**

I have used the following js files

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jcarousellite.js">`

following is the code

`$("#Expand"+id).toggle(500);`

Comment: Consider adding some of your code - without it, there's no way to understand what the issue is. A basic guess - this is probably a CSS animation issue, not PhoneGap-related.

Comment: I added my code .